# How to open GRIB data in GIS software?

Tags: geospatial

I have downloaded soil moisture files but they are in [GRIB format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB) and I don't know how to read them or display them in GIS software like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) or [Saga GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html).

How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [similar questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grib) in the [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has the [Crayfish Plugin](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/products/crayfish/) for reading GRIB data.

Comment: Thanks, but I opened it in Integrated Data Viewer (IDV)